# Merging empty pandas DF with rows from separate DF on Google Sheets

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with this Google Sheets sheet here 
(https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1I2VIGfJOyod-13Fke8Prn8IkhpgZWbirPBbosm8EFCc/edit?usp=sharing)
and I want to create a similar dataframe that ONLY consists of the cells that contain "OOO" at the end (I have highlighted them in yellow for clarity). As an example, here's a small snippet of what I want to get out of it:
(https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rRWgESE7kPTvchOL0RxEcqjEnY9oUsiMnov-qagHg7I/edit?usp=sharing)

Basically I want to create my own 'schedule' here.

```py
import os
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import pandas as pd
from googleapiclient import discovery


DATA_DIR = '/path/here/'
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
path = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'client_secret.json')
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(path, scope)
client = gspread.authorize(credentials)
service = discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials)
spreadsheet_id = 'Dcon19'

debug = False

spreadsheet = client.open(spreadsheet_id).sheet1
data = spreadsheet.get_all_values()
index = str(data[0][0])
headers = data.pop(0)
df_index = []

def conv_pd_df():

    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=headers, index=None)
    df = df.set_index(index)
    df_index.append(df.index.values)

    mask = df.applymap(lambda x: key in str(x))
    df1 = df[mask.any(axis=1)]

    return df1


def highlight(df1):
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=headers[1:], index=df_index) # blank dataframe
    df2 = df2.fillna('none', inplace=True)
    for col in df1: 
        update_row = df1[df1[col].str.contains("OOO")]
        if not update_row.empty:
            try:
                df2.update(update_row, overwrite=True)
            except AttributeError as e:
                print(f'Error {e}')
    df2.to_csv('/path/dcon.csv', header=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if not debug:
        df1 = conv_pd_df()
        highlight(df1)
```

Now the only thing I'm getting back as df2 is a blank dataframe because I come to the error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to_csv'` when I try to save the resultant df2.

Does anyone know how to get this working, or a more efficient way to accomplish this?

This is my first real personal project so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you reference is because of the way you used `fillna`.  `df2.fillna('none', inplace=True)` will return `None` which is what you are seeing as an error when to try to send `df2.to_csv...`

Try something like this for your highlight function.

```
def highlight(df1):
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=headers[1:], index=df_index) # blank dataframe
    df2.fillna('none', inplace=True)
    for col in df1: 
        update_row = df1[df1[col].str.contains("OOO")]
        if not update_row.empty:
            try:
                df2.update(update_row, overwrite=True)
            except AttributeError as e:
                print(f'Error {e}')
    df2.to_csv('/path/dcon.csv', header=True)
```